# .htaccess bind Apache server to ldap causes Internal server error 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-auth

Using wamp server with apache 2.4.4

I have a directory that I want to protect with .htaccess file:

```
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication required "
AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://myldap:389/ou=p1,dc=dt,dc=mycompany,dc=local?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)"

AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=admin,dc=dt,dc=mycompany,dc=local"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "password"
Require valid-user
```

I have AllowOverride all set in httpd.conf.

I have all LoadModule directives uncommented in httpd.conf

I can successfully create connection to the ldap using Apache Directory Studio using these BindDN and password.

I can also successfully query ldap://myldap:389/ou=p1,dc=dt,dc=mycompany,dc=local?uid?sub?(objectClass=*) using Windows Explorer

EDIT:
I get the authentication window as it should be but whatever creditentials I enter I get Internal Server Error 500.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if there are any errors in the apache error log please attach them..

Comment: None... Nothing in the console and in the logs dir there is only access.log but no errors there...